# formatting data using the map function + getting an array inside an array but don't want

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to use map to fomat my data in a certain way.

what I want('values' is an array of objects):

```
[{name:"testmodel",values[{val1:"val1",...,val5:"val5"}]},
{name:"testmodel2",values[{val1:"val1",...,val5:"val5"}]},
...
{name:"testmodelN",values[{val1:"val1",...,val5:"val5"}]}
]
```

what I am getting('values' is an array of objects in side an array):

```
[{name:"testmodel",values[[{val1:"val1",...,val5:"val5"}]]},
{name:"testmodel2",values[[{val1:"val1",...,val5:"val5"}]]},
...
{name:"testmodelN",values[[{val1:"val1",...,val5:"val5"}]]}
]
```

this is my data

```
data_p = [
    [   {"key":"Device_Model","value":"test_model"},
        {"key":">20MB/30","value":"11"},
        {"key":">200MB/30","value":"33"},
        {"key":">2048MB/30","value":"10"},
        {"key":">5120MB/30","value":"55"},
        {"key":">10240MB/30","value":"10"}
    ],
    [{"key":"Device_Model","value":"0P6B670"},{"key":">20MB/30","value":"9"},{"key":">200MB/30","value":"8"},{"key":">2048MB/30","value":"2"},{"key":">5120MB/30","value":"23"},{"key":">10240MB/30","value":"23"}],
    [{"key":"Device_Model","value":"0P6B680"},{"key":">20MB/30","value":"1"},{"key":">200MB/30","value":"23"},{"key":">2048MB/30","value":"23"},{"key":">5120MB/30","value":"23"},{"key":">10240MB/30","value":"23"}],
    [{"key":"Device_Model","value":"0P6B810"},{"key":">20MB/30","value":"5"},{"key":">200MB/30","value":"4"},{"key":">2048MB/30","value":"1"},{"key":">5120MB/30","value":"1"},{"key":">10240MB/30","value":"1"}],
    [{"key":"Device_Model","value":"0P6B900"},{"key":">20MB/30","value":"4"},{"key":">200MB/30","value":"4"},{"key":">2048MB/30","value":"1"},{"key":">5120MB/30","value":"23"},{"key":">10240MB/30","value":"23"}]]
```

thsi is my map function:

```
var bar = color.domain().map(function(name){            
    return {            
      name: name,           
      values: data_p.map(function(d){
        a=[]
        a.push(d[1])
        a.push(d[2])
        a.push(d[3])
        a.push(d[4])
        a.push(d[5])
      return a;                     
      })
    }       
})
```

the above wont work as the `color` library is not available here but this should give you what I am getting

```
data_p.map(function(d){
        a=[]
        a.push(d[1])
        a.push(d[2])
        a.push(d[3])
        a.push(d[4])
        a.push(d[5])
      return a;                     
      })
```

this is what I get:

```
    bar
    [Object { name="test_model",  values=[5]}, Object { name="0P6B670",  values=[5]}, Object { name="0P6B680",  values=[5]}, Object { name="0P6B810",  values=[5]}, Object { name="0P6B900",  values=[5]}]
    bar[0]["values"]
    [[Object { key=">20MB/30",  value="11"}, Object { key=">200MB/30",  value="33"}, Object { key=">2048MB/30",  value="10"}, Object { key=">5120MB/30",  value="55"}, Object { key=">10240MB/30",  value="10"}]],...
    bar[0]["values"][0]
    [Object { key=">20MB/30",  value="11"}, Object { key=">200MB/30",  value="33"}, Object { key=">2048MB/30",  value="10"}, Object { key=">5120MB/30",  value="55"}, Object { key=">10240MB/30",  value="10"}]
```

above  i am very close but in side `bar[0]["values"]` I have an array of objects inside the values array. What I want is `values` to be an array of objects.

this is what I want:(note that this `values` is an array of objects)

```
bar[0]["values"]
[Object { key=">20MB/30",  value="11"}, Object { key=">200MB/30",  value="33"}, Object { key=">2048MB/30",  value="10"}, Object { key=">5120MB/30",  value="55"}, Object { key=">10240MB/30",  value="10"}]
```

---

### EDIT1

this is what I want

```
[{name:"testmodel",values[{ key=">20MB/30",  value="11"}, { key=">200MB/30",  value="33"}, { key=">2048MB/30",  value="10"}, { key=">5120MB/30",  value="55"}, { key=">10240MB/30",  value="10"}]},
{name:"testmodel2",values[{ key=">20MB/30",  value="11"}, { key=">200MB/30",  value="33"}, { key=">2048MB/30",  value="10"}, { key=">5120MB/30",  value="55"}, { key=">10240MB/30",  value="10"}]},
...
{name:"testmodelN",values[[{val1:"val1",...,val5:"val5"}]]}
]
```

when I use what you say I get this, the 25 key/values for each name. I jsut want 5 key/vals per name.

```
   [{name:"testmodel",values[{val1:"val1",...,val25:"val25"}]},
    {name:"testmodel2",values[{val1:"val1",...,val25:"val25"}]},
    ...
    {name:"testmodelN",values[{val1:"val1",...,val25:"val25"}]}
    ]
```

---

### EDIT2

tks to @trincot Answer below, broke this down just for my reference.
did the below in the console.

```
//1 
aa=data_p.filter(function(d){
        return d[0].value == "test_model";
      })
aa
//2
aa=data_p.filter(function(d){
        return d[0].value == "test_model";
      })[0]
aa
//3
aa=data_p.filter(function(d){
        return d[0].value == "test_model";
      })[0].slice(1)
aa
```

Comment: Your question is unclear precisely because we don't have the output from the `color.domain()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter the data by the name you pass in the outer callback function. This you can do with `filter` (or in modern browsers with `find`). On the filtered item you can then take the elements with `slice` so that you exclude the first element containing the name:

```
var bar = color.domain().map(function(name){            
    return {            
      name: name,     
      values: data_p.filter(function(d){
        return d[0].value == name;
      })[0].slice(1)
    }
})
```

Comment: tks, the reduce gives me 25 values, I only want 5 per name. tks for the other advice.

Comment: Then I don't understand why you want something like `map` at all, since you already have 5 elements pushed, so if you don't want more, it should not be in a loop at all. But now I don't understand which 5 you want, even after rereading your question. Your `data_p` has 25 such values... Does `name` have to match with something? Can you clarify?

Comment: Anyway, I have updated my answer to what I think you want to happen to only get 5 elements.

Comment: see my EDIT1, but I think you got it with that answer, tks.